# How to hide the element on textbox blur event and show it again on focus

Tags: javascript

I am checking username availability. when focus is set on the username textbox the username availability is show onkeyup event using ajax. 
But when set focus or select other textbox the 'username available' or 'not available' text does not hide it stays there besides username textbox as it is 
So please advice me some code for hiding the text.
Here is my jsp page

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
function cleanup(){
    document.getElementById("usernameAvail").removeAttribute("value");
}


function loadXMLDoc()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    var j = document.getElementById("usertype").value;
    var k=document.getElementById("username").value;


    if(j=="students")
    {   

        var urls="passS.jsp?ver="+k;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
            {
                //document.getElementById("err").style.color="red";
                document.getElementById("usernameAvail").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("POST",urls,true);
        xmlhttp.send(); 
    }   
    else if(j=="mentors")
    {
        var urls="passM.jsp?ver="+k;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
            {
                //document.getElementById("err").style.color="red";
                document.getElementById("usernameAvail").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("POST",urls,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <p id="heading">Please Register</p>
    </div>
    <div id="hr"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <form id="RegistrationForm" action="RegisterServlet" method="post">

                <p><label for="usertype">User Type</label></p>

                <select id="usertype" name="usertype">
                    <option disabled selected>select user</option>
                    <option value="mentors">Mentor</option>
                    <option value="students">Student</option>
                </select>

                <p><label for="username">User Name</label></p>
                <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username" onblur="cleanup()" onkeyup="loadXMLDoc()" />
                <span id="usernameAvail"></span>

                <p><label for="firstname">First Name</label></p>
                <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter First Name" />

                <p><label for="lastname">Last Name</label></p>
                <input id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" />

                <p><label for="email">Email ID</label></p>
                <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" />                

                <p><label for="password">Password</label></p>
                <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />          

                <p><label for="cpassword">Confirm password</label></p>
                <input id="cpassword" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Confirm password" />

                <br />
                <br />
                <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up"/>
                <input class="button" type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"/>

        </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: You're not setting the value attribute on the usernameAvail span, so why would you try to remove the attribute (Hint: spans don't have value attributes)?

Answer (score 0):

On blur event your directly removing. Before removing just check in the input field value is exist or not. If exist don't remove it, otherwise you can remove it.

I Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use "**onblur**" event instead of "**keyup**" event. For hiding the "**Error**" or "**Success**" message you can use **Jquery** plugin for auto hiding both messages after few seconds . Like following two examples.

http://pjdietz.com/jquery-plugins/freeow/

http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/jnotify#field_screenshots

Also I recommended you to use Jquery Ajax method instead of using simple "**xmlhttp**". Following is the example using Jquery Ajax.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-ajax.htm

Hope its help.!!